# How to use the firestore generated id to create a slug

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to use the newly created firestore document id to generate a slug(title+id).

On my website, users can create solutions(documents), so I want to create a slug using the document id of the generated solution at the time of generating the solution and then redirect the user to that slug after the solution creation.

Here is my code:

```js
const StartCodingButton = ({ document, setIsOpen }) => {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  const { addDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")
  const { push } = useRouter()

  const { documents } = useCollection(
    "solutions",
    solutionDetails[0].challengeID
  )

  const initializeCodeEditor = async () => {
    if (documents.length > 0) {
      setIsOpen(false)
      push(`/playground/${documents[0].id}`)
    } else {
      const addedDocument = await addDocument({
        ...document,
        author:
          user.displayName !== null ? user.displayName : user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        userID: user.uid,
        slug: id+document.title // here I want to generate the slug
      })

      if (addedDocument) {
        setIsOpen(false)
        const id = addedDocument.id
        // redirect the user to the generated slug
        push(`/playground/${id}`)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```js
slug: `${document.title}-${id}`.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-')
```

Obviously you would also change the bottom function to:

```js
if (addedDocument) {
        setIsOpen(false)
        push(`/playground/${addedDocument.slug}`)
}
```

#### Ah - I see your question now - how to create the slug if the document Id is not yet available

That is a common problem and the simplest solution is to *not* create the slug immediately, but rather *after* addDocument returns a result.

```js
const addedDocument = await addDocument({
  ...document,
  author: user.displayName !== null ? user.displayName : user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
  userID: user.uid
})

if (addedDocument) {
  await db.collection("solutions").doc(addedDocument.id).update({
    slug: `${document.title}-${id}`.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-')
  });
  setIsOpen(false)
  const id = addedDocument.id
  push(`/playground/${id}`)
}
```

Comment: But I want to use the id of the solution document that I'm creating.

Comment: @r121 You already have the id available, right? I'm not sure what different thing you're looking for than what you already have (`push('/playground/${id}')`)...

Comment: but I don't have access to that `id` inside the `addDocument()`. I need the `addedDocument.id` inside the `addDocument` to generate a slug.